# solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory returns incorrect results

Tags: solr

Using *solr-spec 6.1.0* and *lucene-spec 6.1.0*

I have a field that uses EdgeNGramFilterFactory and I see incorrect results.

I am querying for title "raza" and it returns me the documents with title "raza" and as well all other titles where it finds "r" "ra" "raz".

Analysis UI shows me that the offsets are not properly set

Check the screenshot from Analysis UI here

[image]

I see the "end" is constant 4,4,4,4. Which I think should be 1,2,3,4

Configuration from Schema.xml below

```
<field name="full_name" type="text_prefix" indexed="true" stored="true" storeOffsetsWithPositions="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_prefix" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="_" replacement=" "/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="1"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="_" replacement=" "/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I tried the same schema on my other environment using older version of Solr and Lucene as below [**luceneMatchVersion="4.3"**] and it works fine

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="1" luceneMatchVersion="4.3"/>
```

But with latest Solr 6.1.0, it doesn't work.

Can someone please help me with a fix for this to work on Solr 6.1.0

Comment: Can you post your field's full definition in the schema. Not just the one filter.

Comment: I have included the configuration/definition from Schema.xml now. Thanks Alexandre for checking it out.